# How to prove list concatenation is not commutative using coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coq-extraction

Sorry I am new to coq. I'm wondering how to prove list concatenation is not commutative using coq?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to exhibit a counterexample. For instance:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Theorem list_app_is_not_commutative :
  ~ (forall A (l1 l2 : list A), l1 ++ l2 = l2 ++ l1).
Proof.
intros H.
specialize (H bool [true] [false]).
simpl in H.
congruence.
Qed.
```

Comment: or simply (see [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=discriminate#coq:tacn.discriminate))
`intros H; discriminate (H bool [true] [false]).`

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use exist tactic following your logic but get stuck:


Theorem list_app_is_not_commutative :
  ~ (exists A (l1 l2 : list A), l1 ++ l2 = l2 ++ l1).
Proof.
exists  bool [true] [false].

The error message says "Not an inductive goal with 1 constructor." Why can't I use exist tactic here?

Comment: `exists` should be on top of the negation. your goal should be `exists A (l1 l2 : list A), l1 ++ l2 <> l2 ++ l1`

Comment: the `exists` tactic is fine but the `exists ` must be the top constructor of you goal otherwise it will fail with the error message you got.

Comment: If written in the following form `exists l1 l2, l1++ l2 <> l2 ++ l1`, then you unknowingly wrote two nested existential quantifications, the right way to provide witnesses is `exists [true]; exists [false].` treating each existential quantification separately.  There is also a shorter way of writing it `exists [true], [false].`

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
From Coq Require Import List.

Import ListNotations.

Goal [true] ++ [false] <> [false] ++ [true].
Proof. easy. Qed.
```